# Why doesn't my authentication service find the user?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, sequelize.js

I am developing an authentication service for my API with nodejs expressjs jwt and sequelize.

When I authenticate the user meaning I am logging in, I get a success response and a token.

But later I want to send a request to another route to get the information of the current logged in user and I pass the token, I get an error

> User not found

This is my route in routes/api/auth.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { protect } = require('../../middleware/auth'); 

const {
    register,
    login,
    getMe,
} = require('../../controllers/auth');

router.post('/register', register);
router.post('/', login);
router.get( '/me', protect, getMe);

module.exports = router;
```

This is my controller methods:

```
//@route   POST api/auth
//@desc    Authenticate user & get token
//@access  public

exports.login = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    //Validate email and password
    if(!email || !password){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Please provide an email and password'}]});
    }

    //See if user exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email }, attributes: ['email', 'password'] });

    if(!user){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg:'Invalid credentials' }] });
    }

    //Compare the input password, plane text, to the encrypted password.
    const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
    
    if(!isMatch){
        return res.status(401).json({ errors: [{ msg:'Invalid credentials' }] });
    }

    //Return jsonwebtoken -> this for users to be logged in right after registration
    sendTokenResponse(user, 200, res);

});

//@desc   Get current logged in user
//@route  GET api/auth/me
//@access Private

exports.getMe = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findByPk(req.user.id);

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: user
    });
})

//Get Token from model, create a cookie and send response

const sendTokenResponse = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    // Create token
    const token = user.getSignedJwtToken();
  
    const options = {
      expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
      httpOnly: true
    };
  
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      options.secure = true;
    }
  
    res
      .status(statusCode)
      .cookie('token', token, options)
      .json({
        success: true,
        token
      });
  };
```

This is my middleware with a method to protect routes:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const asyncHandler = require('./async');
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');
const User = require('../models/User.model');

//Protect Routes 
exports.protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;

    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.cookies.token) {
        token = req.cookies.token;
    }

    //Make sure token exists
    if(!token){
        return next(new ErrorResponse('Not authorized to access this route', 401));
    }

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const user = await User.findByPk(decoded.id);
        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse('User not found', 404));
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse('Not authorized to access this route', 401));
    }
    
    
});
```

And this is a method in my User model to sign the token:

```
User.prototype.getSignedJwtToken = function() {
    return jwt.sign({ id: this.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
       expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE
    });
};
```

When I send a request to `http://localhost:5000/api/auth` I send as headers `content-type application/json` with the email and password

As a response I get the following example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE3MDY4MjI4NjgsImV4cCI6MTcwOTQxNDg2OH0.1ThbbIojSnBWcmdMzp6z2lvtA6skR6J-aoEYqk2pLfM"
}
```

Later I send a request to `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/me`

In my headers I send `content-type application/json` and `Authorization  Bearer <TOKEN FROM ABOVE>`

And as a response I get `User not found`

I've tried debugging my code and adding more error messages, but I am not certainly sure if is it that my token not storing it correctly the user information or what.

Comment: Can you show your whole sequelize model? Your code looks correct, but the token you posted definitely does not contain the payload.

Comment: In your protect function, can you log the value of the user?  const user = await User.findByPk(decoded.id); Can you confirm user contains data? Seems the user data here is empty.